# T-SQL looping procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have the following data:

```
ID       Date                 interval  interval_date            tot_activity  non-activity
22190   2011-09-27 00:00:00     1000    2011-09-27 10:00:00.000     265           15
```

I have another table with this data:

```
Date                        ID             Start                END               sched_non_activity     non_activity
10/3/2011 12:00:00 AM   HBLV-22267  10/3/2011 2:02:00 PM    10/3/2011 2:11:00 PM    540
```

Now, in the second table's non_activity field, I would like this to be the value from the first table. However, I need to capture the tot_activity - non_activity where the intervals(in 15 min increments) from the first table, fall in the same time frame as the start and end of the second table.

I have tried setting variables and setting a loop where for each row it verifies the starttime by interval, but I have no idea how to return a variable with only one record, as I keep getting errors that my variable is getting too many results.

I have tried looking everywhere for tutorials and I can't find anything to help me out. Anyone have any pointers or tutorials on looping they could share?

Comment: Could you explain this question in more detail?  What do you mean by "I need to capture".  I understand that you want the non_activity in the second table to take on the value of the non-activity field in the first table, but what else did you need to capture?

Comment: In the first table, it is by 15 minute intervals. So 15:00,15:15,15:30, etc. In the second table, it has a start and end time in normal hh:mm:ss. I need to cross-check the second table's sched_non_activity with the first tables tot_activity - non_activity where the intervals and time of the second table match. So if the start of second table is 15:55, I need the interval for table1 of 15:45 to be included. Hope this is clear enough :)

Comment: I think you should post what you have tried. Even though your attempts resulted in errors, they might help to understand your intent better. One other thing that could be helpful is a data sample accompanied by the expected result produced off that sample. Your problem seems to be a tricky one, and verbal description alone doesn't seem sufficient to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate the interval end dates somehow; I'm assuming that there is always a record in the first table with a 15 minute interval record. In this case, an example would look like this:

```
;WITH Intervals
AS
(SELECT
     Interval_date
     ,DATEADD(ms,840997,Interval_date) AS interval_end
    ,nonactivity
FROM A)

--Select query for Validation
--SELECT 
--  b.[Date]
--  ,b.ID 
--  ,b.Start
--  ,b.sched_non_activity
--  ,i.nonactivity
--FROM B
--JOIN Intervals AS i
--ON b.Start >= i.Interval_date 
--AND b.[END] <= i.interval_end 

UPDATE B
    SET non_activity = i.nonactivity
FROM  B
JOIN Intervals AS i
ON b.Start >= i.Interval_date   
AND b.[END] <= i.interval_end
```

Obviously, you might need to tweak this depending on the exact circumstances.